# Play Youtube Videos with Swift

Tags: swift

Hey I want to display a youtube video in my app but if I run it there is only a black screen ??

```
func playVideo() {
    var audioplayer : MPMoviePlayerController!

    var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://youtu.be/7n1KPclvGQY.mp4")!

    var MPMoviePlayerViewController = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)

    MPMoviePlayerViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 200, height: 150)
    MPMoviePlayerViewController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File

    self.view.addSubview(MPMoviePlayerViewController.view)
    MPMoviePlayerViewController.prepareToPlay()
    MPMoviePlayerViewController.play()
    MPMoviePlayerViewController.pause()
    }
```

Comment: i deleted : MPMoviePlayerViewController.pause() but it still does not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing youtube video with MPMoviePlayerController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198169/playing-youtube-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller)

Comment: Thats not swift and another problem :/

Comment: Could it be because you're pausing it immediately after playing it?

Comment: i already deleted it but it still does not work

Comment: Being Swift or Objective-C should not be an issue. Both are using CocoaTouch, and in our case `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. It seems according to the possible duplicate, that it doesn't do it without modification.

Answer (score 0):

There's no really nice way to do this. There is [this library](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView) but it breaks YouTube's TOS.

Best to call `[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:...]` which will open in safari or the YouTube app, if they have it installed.

If its content you own, perhaps try hosting it yourself and using the same method yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom library for playing youtube video
Make use of custom https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView

It is a subclass of MPMoviePlayerViewController.

LBYouTubeView is just a small view that is able to display YouTube videos in a MPMoviePlayerController. You even have the choice between high-quality and standard quality stream.

It just loads the HTML code of YouTube's mobile website and looks for the data in the script tag.

LBYouTubeView doesn't use UIWebView which makes it faster and look cleaner.