# How to play youtube video using MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, video-streaming

I want to play video of youtube url.
I'm using below code but it is not working.

```
-(void)playVideoFromURL
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s","https://www.youtube.com/embed/96ReVjMAXEE?autoplay=1&vq=small"]];
    self.videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.videoController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    self.videoController.repeatMode=MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    self.videoController.fullscreen=YES;
    self.videoController.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    self.videoController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,self.videoplayview.frame.size.width, self.videoplayview.frame.size.height);
    [self.videoplayview addSubview:self.videoController.view];
    [self.videoController play];
}
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198169/playing-youtube-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller

Comment: I don't think you can play youtube videos in any player, except youtube own. They have an SDK, you need to use their provided youtube player to play videos from youtube.

Comment: Use `youtube-iso-player-helper` is impossible with `MPMoviePlayerController`

Comment: i am also having the same issue . have you solved it ? if yes then please guide me through this . or did you use another scenario or methodology or player ?

Comment: @Moxarth I was designed cutom View like YTPlayerView with next and previous button and seekbar (seekbar created using progressbar).

Comment: @MonikaPatel thats even great . i will look into that and try to implement as you have guided . thanks a lot .

Comment: @Moxarth welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot play a YouTube vidoe URL in MPMoviePlayerController. For this you have to use

[youtube-iso-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) - But you cannot play private video URL in youtube-iso-player-helper

[XCDYoutubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit) - It is against YouTube Terms and Service.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to directly play a youtube video with MPMoviePlayerController because youtube does not expose direct links to the video files.

The only way to have a youtube video play inside your own app is to create a UIWebView with the embed tag from Youtube for the movie you want to play as the UIWebView's content. UIWebView will detect that the embedded object is a Youtube link, and the web view's content will be the youtube preview for the video. When your user clicks the preview, the video will be shown in an MPMoviePlayerController.